# convert a bash script with dialog to python

Tags: python, linux, bash

I currently have a [bash script](https://github.com/Patlol/Handy-Install-Web-Server-ruTorrent-) that installs a web server with many options and features.
Currently I download the script on the remote linux server and execute it via ssh.

This script uses Dialog so that the end user can enter information such as user name, password to create. Path to use, domain name etc....

I would like to rewrite this script which has become huge in python, keeping an interactivity of the same type (dialog). Is there a solution / module with python? Knowing that the remote server on which the script run is a server without a graphical system like Qt, Gtk just console. I think it is necessary to use curses
bash dialog definition :

> Dialog is a utility to create nice user interfaces to shell scripts,
>   or other scripting languages, such as perl. It is non-graphical (it
>   uses curses) so it can be run in the console or an xterm.

exemple:
[image]

I'm looking for an equivalent on python
Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you read about [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to create dialog boxes in python, or is there a handy way to install/setup web server with python?

Comment: way to create dialog boxes or equivalent in python

Comment: If you want software recommendations, [su] is better place to ask this question.

Comment: @patol. Sounds like you want [pythondialog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pythondialog/3.4.0).

Comment: YES, thanks, and there are a complete doc here http://pythondialog.sourceforge.net/doc/

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways to create dialog box type UIs for python. [PyQt](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro) is one of the more powerful ones. [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html) is also handy for simple tasks. Or at least I like to use it for simple stuff. Either one should get what you need. There's probably more I missed as well.

**EDIT**

If it's a CLI you want, there are plenty of tool. [Here's a neat looking one.](http://click.pocoo.org/6/)

Comment: yes but a linux server don't have windows manager. I use in my bash script "dialog" is not a graphic UI

Comment: Ah I misunderstood. The python is running on the linux machine? And you want a command line interface?

Comment: Yes a command line interface, without a graphical system like Qt, Gtk just console.